# Is there any way to capture 'Error Details' from data flow activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to capture Error Details from Data Flow Activity in case of any error and use it to log into database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression to get error message from Data Flow:

```
@activity('Data Flow name').error.message
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried this but got an error as the data flow activity output does not have 'error' key.

Comment: Can you show me your screenshot of pipeline? I can get it by this expression.